# Cut off the filename and extension of a given string

Tags: ruby, regex, string, path

I build a little script that parses a directory for files of a given filetype and stores the location (including the filename) in an array. This look like this:

```
def getFiles(directory)
  arr = Dir[directory + '/**/*.plt']
  arr.each do |k|
    puts "#{k}"
  end
end
```

The output is the path and the files. But I want only the path.

Instead of /foo/bar.txt I want only the /foo/

My first thought was a regexp but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could [File.dirname](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/File.html#M002565) be of any use?

> **File.dirname(file_name ) → dir_name**
>
> Returns all components of the filename
>   given in file_name except the last
>   one. The filename must be formed using
>   forward slashes (``/’’) regardless of
>   the separator used on the local file
>   system.
>
> ```
> File.dirname("/home/gumby/work/ruby.rb") #=> "/home/gumby/work"
> ```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex or split.

```
File.dirname("/foo/bar/baz.txt")
# => "/foo/bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work (tested in the ruby console):

```
>> path = "/foo/bar/file.txt"
=> "/foo/bar/file.txt"
>> path[0..path.rindex('/')]
=> "/foo/bar/"
```

rindex finds the index of the last occurrence of substring. Here is the documentation http://docs.huihoo.com/api/ruby/core/1.8.4/classes/String.html#M001461

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would split it into an array by the slashes, then remove the last element (the filename), then join it into a string again.

```
path = '/foo/bar.txt'

path = path.split '/'
path.pop
path = path.join '/'

# path is now '/foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what language your in but here is the regex for the last / to the end of the string.

```
/[^\/]*+$/
```

Transliterates to all characters that are not '/' before the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

For a regular expression, this should work, since * is greedy:

```
.*/
```